# How to catch inserted data before SaveChanges in WCF Data Services

Tags: c#, wcf-data-services

I have a WCF Data Service that provides access to one of my tables like this:

```
public static void InitializeService(DataServiceConfiguration config)
 {
      // TODO: set rules to indicate which entity sets and service operations are visible, updatable, etc.    
      config.SetEntitySetAccessRule("Data", EntitySetRights.All);
 }
```

I don't have any insert methods, the clients send a post request with the data and the Data Service gets the insert done (default mode).

Unfortunately, the incoming data has some data type error, so I should *catch* it and *alter* it before any `SaveChanges` happens.

How could I do that? Is there any method to override to get the incoming object?

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can use the [ChangeInterceptor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd744842%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) mechanism, by adding this code:

```
[ChangeInterceptor("Data")]
public void OnChangeData(Data data, UpdateOperations updateOperation)
{
  if (updateOperation == UpdateOperations.Add)
  {
     //do your job
  }
}
```

Unfortunately for me, it is too late as the object is alread deserialized here (and I get the exception in the Deserialization phase).